# Servlet handling POST request as GET

Tags: java, http, servlets

I wrote a servlet to handle both POST and GET requests, based on the example given [here](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/java-servlets-2). I have the following:

A html with the following form:

```
form method="POST" action="servlet/RequestType"
```

and input:

```
input type="submit" value="POST"
```

The following `doGet` and `doPost` methods:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse rsp)   throws ServletException, IOException {
    rsp.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = rsp.getWriter();

    String requestType = req.getMethod();

    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head><title> Request Type: " + requestType
       + " </title></head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<p>This page is the result of a " + requestType
    + " request.</p>");
    out.println("</body></html>");
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse rsp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(req, rsp);
}
```

The output should be:

> This page is the result of a POST request.

But I'm getting:

> This page is the result of a GET request.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: I can't see your HTML. Are you sure the attribute method="POST" is set in your HTML <form> element?

Try removing the doPost method.  You should have a message saying the operation is not supported.

Comment: Yes, I just edited my post to show how my form is, it wasn't showing before, because of the html tags, I think. Anyway, this is my form:
<form method="POST" action="servlet/RequestType"> 
   <input type="submit" value="POST" /> 
</form>

Comment: I had a similar problem.. check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695795/html-form-method-post-calls-java-servlet-doget-method

Answer (score 2):

I know, that isn't solve, but try to check request method in doPost() before call doGet(). 
Use System.out.println() - you will see what will be written. If nothing will be written it will mean, that your request is always GET.

Answer (score 0):

You need to press the submit button of the form to send a POST request.

<sub>*That said, this tutorial from 2001 gives me a lot of itch. I'd suggest to go read a more recent/decent one.*</sub>

Comment: Yeah, BalusC, I pressed. That's why I got that outcome. I'll try looking for another tutorial. Any suggestions? Thank you!