# HTML form method POST calls java servlet doGet method

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, servlets, post

I have an HTML form like this:

form.html:

```
<html>
<body>

 your name is :<br><br>

<form ACTION="../post2" METHOD="POST">
<input name="name" type="text" id="name"/>
<input name="send"  type="submit"  value="send"/>
</form>

</body>
<html>
```

The servlet to serve this request:

post2.class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

    public class post2 extends HttpServlet
    {

protected void doDo(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
 throws IOException{

String name = request.getParameter("name");

response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

out.println("<HTML><BODY>");
out.println("<H2>hello "+name+"</H2>");
out.println("<BR><BR>");
out.println("info:");
out.println("<BR><BR>");
out.println("<H2>metoda GET</H2>");
out.println("<BR><BR>");
out.println("SERVER_NAME="+request.getServerName()+"<BR>");
out.println("REQUEST_METHOD="+request.getMethod()+"<BR>");
out.println("QUERY_STRING="+request.getQueryString()+"<BR>");
out.println("REMOTE_HOST="+request.getRemoteHost()+"<BR>");
out.println("REMOTE_ADDR="+request.getRemoteAddr());
out.println("</BODY></HTML>"); 
}


@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
throws IOException {      
 doDo(request,response);
}

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
throws IOException {
 doDo(request,response);
}

}
```

and the result is :

```
hello null


info:

SERVER_NAME=localhost
REQUEST_METHOD=GET
QUERY_STRING=null
REMOTE_HOST=127.0.0.1
REMOTE_ADDR=127.0.0.1
```

what is wrong ? For me it seems that the servlet don't see post method from form. Please help, Im completly have no idea why it not working properly...

the result from the wireshark:

> 648   126.229267  87.105.184.89   192.168.1.100   HTTP    557 POST /post2
>   HTTP/1.1  (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
>
> 953   379.456916  192.168.1.100   87.105.184.89   HTTP    239 HTTP/1.1 302 Moved
>   Temporarily
>
> 955   379.462518  192.168.1.100   87.105.184.89   HTTP    470 GET /post2/
>   HTTP/1.1
>
> 957   379.463979  192.168.1.100   87.105.184.89   HTTP    431 HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
>   (text/html)

routing logic:

`tomcat\webapps\ROOT\form.html` --> `\tomcat\webapps\post2\WEB-INF\classes\post2.class`

Comment: For a start, you forgot the `</form>` tag.

Comment: Use Wireshark or something to make sure you are actually getting a POST.

Comment: Are you actually submitting the form? For `name` to be null the field can't be submitted; it would be an empty string if there was no value in the input element.

Comment: Oli - it was only a  my misprint during text copy. Francis - ok i just downloading it. Dave - The issue of my problem is that i type a name and i can't get name im typed

Comment: How did you map the servlet? Do you have both a post2 servlet and a post2 directory in the webapp?

Comment: JB Nizet - Yes I have servlet in tomcat\webaps\post2\WEB-INF\classes directory

Comment: Show us the mapping of the servlet in the web.xml. My guess is that you mapped it to / or /*, and you invoke it using the webapp's context path. Try changing the action of your form to "../post2/" instead of "../post2"

Comment: JB Nizet - this is the clue! Thanks for Your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this be due to a redirect? If "/post2" redirects to "/post2/" your POST request would be transformed into a GET, losing all post data.

Try accessing "/post2" directly in your browser and see what happens.

Comment: The same.. i think - REQUEST_METHOD=GET

Comment: Edit your question and add the routing logic, how your framework routes a specific url to your doDo view.

Comment: It seems thats You are right - when I changed redirect from /post2 to /post2/ post method working well. Thanks You:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `value` attribute to the input tag:

```
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" value=""/>
```

And put (enter by typing) a value in there - by default blank fields are not submitted.

For simplicity, try this, which pre-sets the value:

```
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="john"/>
```

Comment: I add the value as You said but this not helps.. BTW when i use in form GET method servlet displays the name properly

Answer (score 0):

The `null` problem occurs because you are not submitting the form to the server.

Answer (score -1):

This solves your problem:

```
String name = request.getParameter("name").toString();
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how/why it solves the problem?  It's better to provide insight instead of just answers.